# How to round off a double value to the nearest integer

Tags: c#

How do I achieve the below rounding?

0.01> 0

1.033>1

1.1>1.5

2.1 > 2.5

2.4 > 2.5

2.5 > 2.5

2.6 > 3

Comment: Got some code for us?

Comment: Are you trying to round to the nearest integer or not? 2.5 is not an integer, and .05 is not an integer.

Comment: You say "`integer`" but with `2.5` as a desired result.

Comment: What is the difference between 0.01 and .01? And you want different result for both of them!!

Comment: A believe rounding to the nearest integer is not what you are wanting to achieve as 2.5 is not an integer, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to round a number up to the nearst 0.5, so that 2.4 is rounded up to 2.5, and 2.6 is rounded up to 3.

So instead of Math.Round you want to use [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Only it rounds up to the nearest whole number, and you want to the nearest half. So, we do this:

```
double RoundUpToHalf(double number)
{
    number *= 2;  // Turn 2.4 to 4.8
    number = Math.Ceiling(number)  // Round up to 5
    return number/2;  // Back to 2.5
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but its not working for 1.01>1 i want all these stuff on one function

Comment: You mean Math.Round(1.01) is *not* 1?!

Comment: No i meant for 16.1>16.5 is not working

Comment: Oh oh oh oh oh, you want to round up to the nearest 0.5. OK, I'll rewrite.